# How can i calculate the distance between two gps points in Java?

Tags: java, gps, coordinates, distance, geo

I used this code but it doesnt work:

Need the distance between two gps coordinates like 41.1212, 11.2323 in kilometers (Java)

```
double d2r = (180 / Math.PI);
double distance = 0;

try{
    double dlong = (endpoint.getLon() - startpoint.getLon()) * d2r;
    double dlat = (endpoint.getLat() - startpoint.getLat()) * d2r;
    double a =
        Math.pow(Math.sin(dlat / 2.0), 2)
            + Math.cos(startpoint.getLat() * d2r)
            * Math.cos(endpoint.getLat() * d2r)
            * Math.pow(Math.sin(dlong / 2.0), 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double d = 6367 * c;

    return d;

} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Your trigonometry approach would work really well if the Earth was a perfect sphere. However, it is actually an ellipsoid, so the radius from the surface to the Earth's core is variable depending on your position on the earth. To get an accurate distance measurement, you need to get a coordinate system library that can account for this. Assuming a sphere may be close enough for whatever you are doing, but if you need it to be very accurate, you'll need to find a good library.

Comment: Duplicated from: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694380/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude-what-am-i-doi][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694380/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude-what-am-i-doi

Answer (score 20):

Longitude and latitude are given in degrees (0-360). If you want to convert degrees to radians (0-2π) you need to divide by 360 and multiply by 2π, (or equivalently, **multiply by π/180**). In your code however, **you multiply by 180/π**.

That is, change

```
double d2r = (180 / Math.PI);
```

into

```
double d2r = Math.PI / 180;
```

Answer (score 11):

have a look a [Geocalc](https://github.com/grumlimited/geocalc)

```
Coordinate lat = new GPSCoordinate(41, .1212);
Coordinate lng = new GPSCoordinate(11, .2323);
Point point = new Point(lat, lng);

lat = new DegreeCoordinate(51.4613418);
lng = new DegreeCoordinate(-0.3035466);
Point point2 = new Point(lat, lng);
System.out.println("Distance is " + EarthCalc.getDistance(point2, point) / 1000 + " km");
```

> Distance is 1448.7325760822912 km

I wrote that library for one my project.

Answer (score 8):

The solution from http://www.androidsnippets.com/distance-between-two-gps-coordinates-in-meter.

Only works if the points are close enough that you can omit that earth is not regular shape.

```
private double gps2m(float lat_a, float lng_a, float lat_b, float lng_b) {
    float pk = (float) (180/3.14169);

    float a1 = lat_a / pk;
    float a2 = lng_a / pk;
    float b1 = lat_b / pk;
    float b2 = lng_b / pk;

    float t1 = FloatMath.cos(a1)*FloatMath.cos(a2)*FloatMath.cos(b1)*FloatMath.cos(b2);
    float t2 = FloatMath.cos(a1)*FloatMath.sin(a2)*FloatMath.cos(b1)*FloatMath.sin(b2);
    float t3 = FloatMath.sin(a1)*FloatMath.sin(b1);
    double tt = Math.acos(t1 + t2 + t3);

    return 6366000*tt;
}
//
```

see [Distance between two GPS coordinates in meter](http://androidsnippets.com/distance-between-two-gps-coordinates-in-meter).

Answer (score 2):

Distance between two points (and lots of other useful things) can be found at: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 1):

http://www.androidsnippets.com/distance-between-two-gps-coordinates-in-meter 
shows that double d2r = (180 / Math.PI);

Answer (score 0):

The distance can be calculated with the Esri Geometry library: [geodesicDistanceOnWGS84](http://esri.github.io/geometry-api-java/javadoc/com/esri/core/geometry/GeometryEngine.html#geodesicDistanceOnWGS84(com.esri.core.geometry.Point,%20com.esri.core.geometry.Point)).

I would assume that JTS also has a method for computing distance.