# Calculating distance between list of Lat/Long

Tags: android, for-loop, geolocation

I have a `List<List<Double>>` in the form of (example list) `[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], ...]`. These are basically list of latitudes and longitudes and I want to calculate the distance between them. I have the distance calculation method which takes in `(Lat1, Lon1, Lat2, Lon2)`.

i.e it takes in (1, 2, 3, 4) from the above list in the first iteration and calculates distance. In the next iteration I need to pass (3,4,5,6) and so on. I can then just add the distances from all iterations to calculate the total distance.

SO I have this method written which takes in 4 values. I am having trouble in developing `for` loop which will pass the correct values to the method that calculates the distance.

Comment: Please post the code you have written

Comment: @MarcinS. I am having trouble writing the for loop and that is the reason for posting it here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate distance between two locations using their longitude and latitude value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981916/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-their-longitude-and-latitu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
List<List<Double>> locations = ...
double totalDistance = 0;
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < locations.size(); i++) {
    List<Double> a = locations.get(i);
    List<Double> b = locations.get(i + 1);
    totalDistance += calcDistance(a, b);
}
```

`calcDistance()` can be the method to calculate the distance between two locations that you mentioned of.

Comment: the CalcDistance takes in 4 points, (1,2) and (3,4) in my case to calculate distance between first 2 points (Say x). then it will take (3,4) and(5,6) and calculate distance (say y). After this I can add up x+y to find out total distance.

Comment: @Intern I just wanted to show you some hints. For example you can call `calcDistance(a.get(0), a.get(1), b.get(0), b.get(1))`…

Comment: Why didn't you show the method signature? It would help a lot