# Match a google maps route using distance range

Tags: android, python, django, google-maps, routeboxer

I'm trying to match if a given location is nearby a given route or within a certain range, im using DJANGO as backend framework, i found this http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/docs/examples.html but it works with javascript, is there a way i can run this on my DJANGO server, or is there something similar that i can use with DJANGO?

Comment: Tried this? https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/mapsengine/v1?hl=en

Comment: yaes, but i dont know if google has an api that can do the match, what i need if to know if a certain location is near by a given route

Comment: Do you really need Maps? There is a similar question about it, but it doesnt use maps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736995/how-can-i-quickly-estimate-the-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points

Comment: that works if you want the distance between two points or a circle around a point but i dont need that :/, not sure if im clear but what i want is like, if you have a route and you have all the restaurants locations, the code should give you all the restaurants that are near to your route by 500 meters for example