# Searching an element in a list of double-nested dictionaries with generator

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaris. In every dictionary, i need to use values, which are in the dictionaries, which are in the dictionaries:

```
[{'Cells': {'Address': 'Нижний Кисельный переулок, дом 3, строение 1',
   'AdmArea': 'Центральный административный округ',
   'District': 'Мещанский район',
   'IsNetObject': 'нет',
   'Name': 'Юнион Джек',
   'OperatingCompany': None,
   'PublicPhone': [{'PublicPhone': '(495) 621-19-63'}],
   'SeatsCount': 30,
   'SocialPrivileges': 'нет',
   'geoData': {'coordinates': [37.62158794615201, 55.76536695660836],
    'type': 'Point'},
   'global_id': 20660594},
  'Id': 'ae3e9479-070f-4d66-9429-de3acd8427ac',
  'Number': 1},
 {'Cells': {'Address': 'проспект Мира, дом 91, корпус 1',
   'AdmArea': 'Северо-Восточный административный округ',
   'District': 'Останкинский район',
   'IsNetObject': 'нет',
   'Name': 'Бар «Джонни Грин Паб»',
   'OperatingCompany': None,
   'PublicPhone': [{'PublicPhone': '(495) 602-45-85'}],
   'SeatsCount': 50,
   'SocialPrivileges': 'нет',
   'geoData': {'coordinates': [37.635709999611, 55.805575000159],
    'type': 'Point'},
   'global_id': 20660628},
  'Id': 'c5301186-00bb-4a1f-af03-6f3237292a51',
  'Number': 2},
```

I'm given coordinates `[lattitude, attitude]`. I want to find the smallest distance between given coordinates and coordinates in dictionaries. So i need to iterate over dictionaries and calculate the distance. 
I'am quite new, but i want to be more proffesional with using a generator to find the distance. But, using `__next__()`, will stop iterating as soon as it meets the condition, so i'am just dont if it is possible.

**So, to be short: What is the most efficient way to find the  smallest distance from a given spot in this data structure?**

Comment: Sorry, but no duplicated keys here!

Comment: @dsgdfg As you can see, all 'Cells' keys are in diffrent dictionaries. Is it still a problem if i need to iterate over these dicts? Thanks you for your advice about geo metrics, but i think i just need a minimum  Euclidian distance

Comment: Don't change the question once people have answered it

Comment: @jonrsharpe nobody answered it yet. The solution doesnt work

Comment: @dsgdfg My points are very close to each other( territiry of 1 town), so i consider WSG as flat coordinates

Comment: @VladislavLadenkov then downvote the solution and comment explaining the problem with it, but don't start moving the goalposts

Comment: @dsgdfg Thank you for your solution, but it implies creating a list of all coordinates. I mentioned, that i dont want a memory-massive solution, i want to iterate over dicts in a list, count the distance, and if it is less than the previus minimum, then remeber it, else - forget

Comment: @jonrsharpe I got you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's assume you have a function get_distance() which finds distance between two points with lat and long. I can describe it, but I think for now it is not the point of the question. Then, the code will be look like:

```
cells = {...} # your data is here
point = [..] # coordinates of the point 
distances = {get_distance(point, cell['Cells']['geoData']['coordinates']): cell['Id'] for cell in cells}  # I don't know do you need a whole entry to be found or only `Id`
closest_id = distances[min(distances.keys())]
```

Off course it is only of possible solutions. I've made it with dict comprehension but sometimes it is more easy to rea to do it with suaul `for` loop. Please let me know if something is unclear.

If you also have problems with writing `get_distance` function - here is an one of examples: [How can I quickly estimate the distance between two (latitude, longitude) points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736995/how-can-i-quickly-estimate-the-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points) (of course it needs to be modified a bit to look like get_distance function)

Comment: Please, see Edit1!

Comment: can't reproduce it... What version of Python do you use? Maybe you can try to go with something like `dict([(get_distance(point, cell['Cells']['geoData']['coordinates']), cell['Id']) for cell in cells])`

Comment: I'am using python 3.5 .  Make it clear for me please, `cells` - the list of dictionaries in your solution?

Comment: Hm, then it should be fine... Yes, cells is a list of dict with addresses

Comment: Above is copy of the code that looks(almost) like yours - I made a typo in variable name, which is doesn't matter although. Code works for me..

Comment: Thanks you, Andrew