# Pandas Latitude-Longitude to distance between successive rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, geospatial, haversine

I have the following in a Pandas DataFrame in Python 2.7:

```
Ser_Numb        LAT      LONG
       1  74.166061 30.512811
       2  72.249672 33.427724
       3  67.499828 37.937264
       4  84.253715 69.328767
       5  72.104828 33.823462
       6  63.989462 51.918173
       7  80.209112 33.530778
       8  68.954132 35.981256
       9  83.378214 40.619652
       10 68.778571 6.607066
```

I am looking to calculate the distance between successive rows in the dataframe. The output should look something like this:

```
Ser_Numb          LAT        LONG   Distance
       1    74.166061   30.512811          0
       2    72.249672   33.427724          d_between_Ser_Numb2 and Ser_Numb1
       3    67.499828   37.937264          d_between_Ser_Numb3 and Ser_Numb2
       4    84.253715   69.328767          d_between_Ser_Numb4 and Ser_Numb3
       5    72.104828   33.823462          d_between_Ser_Numb5 and Ser_Numb4
       6    63.989462   51.918173          d_between_Ser_Numb6 and Ser_Numb5
       7    80.209112   33.530778   .
       8    68.954132   35.981256   .
       9    83.378214   40.619652   .
       10   68.778571   6.607066    .
```

**Attempt**

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767596/using-haversine-formula-with-data-stored-in-a-pandas-dataframe/25767765#25767765) looks somewhat similar but it is calculating the distance between fixed points. I need the distance between successive points.

I tried to adapt this as follows:

```
df['LAT_rad'], df['LON_rad'] = np.radians(df['LAT']), np.radians(df['LONG'])
df['dLON'] = df['LON_rad'] - np.radians(df['LON_rad'].shift(1))
df['dLAT'] = df['LAT_rad'] - np.radians(df['LAT_rad'].shift(1))
df['distance'] = 6367 * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(np.sin(df['dLAT']/2)**2 + math.cos(df['LAT_rad'].astype(float).shift(-1)) * np.cos(df['LAT_rad']) * np.sin(df['dLON']/2)**2))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 115, in <module>
    df['distance'] = 6367 * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(np.sin(df['dLAT']/2)**2 + math.cos(df['LAT_rad'].astype(float).shift(-1)) * np.cos(df['LAT_rad']) * np.sin(df['dLON']/2)**2))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 78, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
[Finished in 2.3s with exit code 1]
```

This error was fixed from MaxU's comment. With the fix, the output of this calculation is not making sense - the distance is nearly 8000 km:

```
   Ser_Numb        LAT       LONG   LAT_rad   LON_rad      dLON      dLAT     distance
0         1  74.166061  30.512811  1.294442  0.532549       NaN       NaN          NaN
1         2  72.249672  33.427724  1.260995  0.583424  0.574129  1.238402  8010.487211
2         3  67.499828  37.937264  1.178094  0.662130  0.651947  1.156086  7415.364469
3         4  84.253715  69.328767  1.470505  1.210015  1.198459  1.449943  9357.184623
4         5  72.104828  33.823462  1.258467  0.590331  0.569212  1.232802  7992.087820
5         6  63.989462  51.918173  1.116827  0.906143  0.895840  1.094862  7169.812123
6         7  80.209112  33.530778  1.399913  0.585222  0.569407  1.380421  8851.558260
7         8  68.954132  35.981256  1.203477  0.627991  0.617777  1.179044  7559.609520
8         9  83.378214  40.619652  1.455224  0.708947  0.697986  1.434220  9194.371978
9        10  68.778571   6.607066  1.200413  0.115315  0.102942  1.175014          NaN
```

According to:

- this [online calculator](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml): If I use Latitude1 = 74.166061,
  Longitude1 = 30.512811, Latitude2 = 72.249672, Longitude2 = 33.427724
  then I get 233 km
- haversine function found
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736995/how-can-i-quickly-estimate-the-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points) as: `print haversine(30.512811, 74.166061, 33.427724, 72.249672)` then I
  get 232.55 km

The answer should be 233 km, but my approach is giving ~8000 km. I think there is something wrong with how I am trying to iterate between successive rows.

**Question:**
Is there a way to do this in Pandas? Or do I need to loop through the dataframe one row at a time?

**Additional Information:**

To create the above DF, select it and copy to clipboard. Then:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
print df
```

Comment: try to replace `math.cos` --> `np.cos`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

you can use [this great solution (c) @derricw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29546836/5741205) (don't forget to upvote it ;-):

```
# vectorized haversine function
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, to_radians=True, earth_radius=6371):
    """
    slightly modified version: of http://stackoverflow.com/a/29546836/2901002

    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees or in radians)

    All (lat, lon) coordinates must have numeric dtypes and be of equal length.

    """
    if to_radians:
        lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = np.radians([lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])

    a = np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2 + \
        np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2

    return earth_radius * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))


df['dist'] = \
    haversine(df.LAT.shift(), df.LONG.shift(),
                 df.loc[1:, 'LAT'], df.loc[1:, 'LONG'])
```

Result:

```
In [566]: df
Out[566]:
   Ser_Numb        LAT       LONG         dist
0         1  74.166061  30.512811          NaN
1         2  72.249672  33.427724   232.549785
2         3  67.499828  37.937264   554.905446
3         4  84.253715  69.328767  1981.896491
4         5  72.104828  33.823462  1513.397997
5         6  63.989462  51.918173  1164.481327
6         7  80.209112  33.530778  1887.256899
7         8  68.954132  35.981256  1252.531365
8         9  83.378214  40.619652  1606.340727
9        10  68.778571   6.607066  1793.921854
```

**UPDATE:** this will help to understand the logic:

```
In [573]: pd.concat([df['LAT'].shift(), df.loc[1:, 'LAT']], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
Out[573]:
           0          1
0        NaN        NaN
1  74.166061  72.249672
2  72.249672  67.499828
3  67.499828  84.253715
4  84.253715  72.104828
5  72.104828  63.989462
6  63.989462  80.209112
7  80.209112  68.954132
8  68.954132  83.378214
9  83.378214  68.778571
```

Comment: I am still getting the error of `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
[Finished in 2.3s with exit code 1]`. Also, I seem to be having trouble with the logic. (A) Why did you use `.shift()` without any argument, (B) was there a reason to use `df.ix[1:,'LONG']` starting from the 2nd row - why not use `df.ix[:,'LONG']` and try to correct for this with `shift(#)`?

Comment: @WR, `shift()` == `shift(1)` (`1` is a default value). Check UPDATE - it'll show pairs of arguments that will be passed to the function...

Comment: Thanks. Ok, code works and I am not getting that `TypeError` anymore. Also, thank you for the **UPDATE** in your answer. That helps. The problem I had was with understanding how to bring the shifted values together with the original values. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @WR, sure, glad i could help

Comment: @MaxU Thank you for your solution! Just one question: why do I get an error in the line `numpy.radians([lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2])`, when `df` has only 2 rows? What does the alternative `map(numpy.radians,[lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2])` work, and is also faster?