# How to call data from a dataframe into Haversine function

Tags: python, function, pandas, haversine

I have a dataframe called lat_long which contains the latitude and longitude of some locations. I want to find the difference between each following location. When I use the example [haversine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767596/using-haversine-formula-with-data-stored-in-a-pandas-dataframe) function, i get an error. KeyError: ('1', u'occurred at index 0').

```
    1         2
0  -6.081689  145.391881
1  -5.207083  145.788700
2  -5.826789  144.295861
3  -6.569828  146.726242
4  -9.443383  147.220050

def haversine(row):
    lon1 = lat_long['1']
    lat1 = lat_long['2']
    lon2 = row['1']
    lat2 = row['2']
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * arcsin(sqrt(a)) 
    km = 6367 * c
    return km

lat_long['distance'] = lat_long.apply(lambda row: haversine(row), axis=1)
lat_long
```

Comment: What do you mean by "distance for each row?"

Comment: I want to find the difference between each following row.

Comment: @AmyRose, is [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40453439/5741205) what you want?

Comment: @MaxU yes, but it keeps telling me 'float' object has no attribute 'radians' I have imported math and numpy..

Comment: @AmyRose, i've added a demo with your data in the answer - please check...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29546836/5741205):

```
def haversine_np(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)

    All args must be of equal length.    

    """
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = np.sin(dlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2.0)**2

    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    km = 6367 * c
    return km
```

Demo:

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]:
        lat         lon
0 -6.081689  145.391881
1 -5.207083  145.788700
2 -5.826789  144.295861
3 -6.569828  146.726242
4 -9.443383  147.220050

In [18]: df['dist'] = \
    ...:     haversine_np(df.lon.shift(), df.lat.shift(), df.ix[1:, 'lon'], df.ix[1:, 'lat'])

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
        lat         lon        dist
0 -6.081689  145.391881         NaN
1 -5.207083  145.788700  106.638117
2 -5.826789  144.295861  178.907364
3 -6.569828  146.726242  280.904983
4 -9.443383  147.220050  323.913612
```

Comment: Thank you very mcuh

Comment: @AmyRose, you are welcome :)