# Computing distance from lat long given in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
      payeeId    latHome   longHome     Total_Amnt
 0  193fde722     0.000000   0.000000        15.0
 1  4d8ecb2b5c   28.425515  77.097547        10.0
 2  2c3ea738     28.542923  77.253164        20.0
 3  2961f3e8     28.542898  77.253162        10.0
 4  5cda3d3763   28.461630  77.031944    129000.0
 5  3cb02ccbfc   26.180680  91.740042       220.0
 6  79918aae03    0.000000   0.000000      1760.0
```

I am trying to compute the distance between two consecutive `latHome` and `longHome`. To do so,I have followed [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452759/pandas-latitude-longitude-to-distance-between-successive-rows) . Below is the function I am using and then applying:

```
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, to_radians=True, earth_radius=6371):
   if to_radians:
      lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = np.radians([lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
   a = np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2 + \
       np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2
   return earth_radius * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))

df_c['Dist_p'] = df_c.apply(haversine(lat1=df_c['latHome'].astype(float).shift(), \
                            lon1 = df_c['longHome'].astype(float).shift(), \
                            lat2 = df_c['latHome'].astype(float), \
                            lon2=df_c['longHome'].astype(float)))
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: no results
```

Also I am getting the below error as well when I am directly using this function i.e. without `apply`.

```
File "<ipython-input-1-3a6c757b499d>", line 13, in haversine
lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = np.radians([lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])

 TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Series which has no callable 
 radians method
```

Any clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- there are multiple libraries and functions for calculating distance.  I have used [geopy](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/)
- key is aligning data / rows to pass to selected distance function.  This use case is `shift(-1)`, however passing **NaN** to this distance function is invalid, hence last row that does not have a next row is defaulted to *(0,0)*

```
import geopy.distance

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""      payeeId    latHome   longHome     Total_Amnt
 0  193fde722     0.000000   0.000000        15.0
 1  4d8ecb2b5c   28.425515  77.097547        10.0
 2  2c3ea738     28.542923  77.253164        20.0
 3  2961f3e8     28.542898  77.253162        10.0
 4  5cda3d3763   28.461630  77.031944    129000.0
 5  3cb02ccbfc   26.180680  91.740042       220.0
 6  79918aae03    0.000000   0.000000      1760.0"""),sep="\s+",)


# prep tuples to pass to geopy.distance
df['Dist_p'] = df.loc[:, ["latHome", "longHome"]].join(
    df.loc[:, ["latHome", "longHome"]].shift(-1).fillna(0), rsuffix="_2"
).apply(
    lambda r: geopy.distance.geodesic(
        (r["latHome"], r["longHome"]), (r["latHome_2"], r["longHome_2"])
    ).km,
    axis=1,
)
```

|  | payeeId | latHome | longHome | Total_Amnt | Dist_p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 193fde722 | 0 | 0 | 15 | 8753.19 |
| 1 | 4d8ecb2b5c | 28.4255 | 77.0975 | 10 | 20.0375 |
| 2 | 2c3ea738 | 28.5429 | 77.2532 | 20 | 0.00277761 |
| 3 | 2961f3e8 | 28.5429 | 77.2532 | 10 | 23.4558 |
| 4 | 5cda3d3763 | 28.4616 | 77.0319 | 129000 | 1476.46 |
| 5 | 3cb02ccbfc | 26.1807 | 91.74 | 220 | 10189.4 |
| 6 | 79918aae03 | 0 | 0 | 1760 | 0 |