# Why does geoshere give the wrong distance?

Tags: r, distance, latitude-longitude

Just checkout the following example:

```
lat <- c(47.5, 47.5, 47.501)
lng <- c(9.3, 9.301, 9.3)
geosphere::distVincentyEllipsoid(lng[c(1,2)], lat[c(1,2)])
# [1] 5551424 Should be about 5000 m?
geosphere::distVincentyEllipsoid(lng[c(1,3)], lat[c(1,3)])
#[1] 5551583 Should be about 5000 m?

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles(group = "OSM") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite") %>%
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM", "Stamen.TonerLite")) %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lat = lat,
                   lng = lng,
                   color = "blue",
                   stroke = FALSE,
                   radius = 3,
                   fillOpacity = 0.7)
print(m)
```

To me it seem, the result is quite off although `????distVincentyEllipsoid` state:

> Distance value in the same units as the ellipsoid (default is meters)

**Edit**: Just as a simple crosscheck from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15742266/5784831):

```
R = 6371  # radius of the earth in km
x = (lng[2] - lng[1]) * cos( 0.5*(lat[2]+lat[1]) )
y = lat[2] - lat[1]
d = R * sqrt( x*x + y*y ) # in km
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supplying `distVincentyEllipsoid` the wrong information. It should have the following format: `distVincentyEllipsoid(p1, p2)`. From the help-file:

```
p1  longitude/latitude of point(s), in degrees 1; can be a vector of two numbers, a matrix of 2 columns (first one is longitude, second is latitude) or a SpatialPoints* object
p2  as above
```

What you are doing is providing the two `lng` values to `p1` and the two `lat` values to `p2`, whereas both points should be a `lng`/`lat` combination.

If you do:

```
distVincentyEllipsoid(c(lng[1], lat[1]), c(lng[2], lat[2]))
```

you will get:

```
[1] 75.34357
```