# Minimize distance between two latitude-longitude points?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to obtain a new columns reporting the minimale distance (km) under condition.

It will be more clear with an example :

```
Ser_Numb        LAT      LONG   VALUE   MIN
       1  74.166061 30.512811       1
       2  72.249672 33.427724       1
       3  67.499828 37.937264       0
       4  84.253715 69.328767       1
       5  72.104828 33.823462       0
       6  63.989462 51.918173       0
       7  80.209112 33.530778       0
       8  68.954132 35.981256       1
       9  83.378214 40.619652       1
       10 68.778571 6.607066        0
```

So when `value=0`, I have to find the closest other city (latitude/longitude) to compute the distance to this city who presents a `VALUE=1`.

With this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736995/how-can-i-quickly-estimate-the-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points) we can have the formula, but how can I adapt it to take the minimal distance ?

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    # Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
    km = 6371* c
    return km
```

**EDIT**
Here is what I try:

```
df['dist_VALUE']=0

for i in range(len(df[df['VALUE']<1])):
    for j in range(len(df[df['VALUE']>0])):
        (df[df['VALUE']<1].reset_index(drop=True).loc[i,'dist_VALUE'] =
         min(haversine(df[df['VALUE']<1].reset_index(drop=True).loc[I,'LONG'], 
         df[df['VALUE']<1].reset_index(drop=True).loc[i,'LAT'],
         df[df['VALUE']>0].reset_index(drop=True).loc[j,'LONG'], 
         df[df['VALUE']>0].reset_index(drop=True).loc[j,'LAT'])))
```

`VALUE` is integer and `LAT` or `LONG` are float.

Comment: for each row where value=0 calculate the distance to all cities that have value=1, and then pick the smales distance. If you want further help you will need to show the code of you datastructure that holds the cities (and mention the data type).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time, I update the question with what I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [74.166061, 30.512811, 1],
        [72.249672, 33.427724, 1],
        [67.499828, 37.937264, 0],
        [84.253715, 69.328767, 1],
        [72.104828, 33.823462, 0],
        [63.989462, 51.918173, 0],
        [80.209112, 33.530778, 0],
        [68.954132, 35.981256, 1],
        [83.378214, 40.619652, 1],
        [68.778571,  6.607066, 0],
    ],
    columns=['lat', 'long', 'val'])
df['min'] = 0
print(df)
# print(df.shape)
# print(df.index)
# print(df.columns)

destination_cities = [
    {
        'i': i,
        'lat': row['lat'],
        'long': row['long'],
    }
    for i, row in df.iterrows()
    if row['val'] == 1]
print('destination_cities')
print(destination_cities)

for i in df.index:
    row = df.iloc[i, :]
    # print(type(row))
    # print(row)

    if row['val'] == 0:
        target_distances = [
            {
                'destination_i': i,
                'distance': haversine(
                    lon1=row['long'],
                    lat1=row['lat'],
                    lon2=destination['long'],
                    lat2=destination['lat']),
            }
            for destination in destination_cities]
        elem = min(target_distances, key=lambda x: x['distance'])
        row = df.loc[i, 'min'] = elem['distance']

print(df)
```

---

Another approach could be to pre-compute the shortest distance for each city and the use `df.apply()` to assign the values; maybe this is a little bit faster for you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [ 1, 74.166061, 30.512811, 1],
        [ 2, 72.249672, 33.427724, 1],
        [ 3, 67.499828, 37.937264, 0],
        [ 4, 84.253715, 69.328767, 1],
        [ 5, 72.104828, 33.823462, 0],
        [ 6, 63.989462, 51.918173, 0],
        [ 7, 80.209112, 33.530778, 0],
        [ 8, 68.954132, 35.981256, 1],
        [ 9, 83.378214, 40.619652, 1],
        [10, 68.778571,  6.607066, 0],
    ],
    columns=['i', 'lat', 'long', 'val'])

# precompute closest distance for each city with val=0 to all cities with val=1
distances = {}
for _, row_orig in df.iterrows():
    if row_orig['val'] == 0:
        distances[row_orig['i']] = min(
            haversine(
                lon1=row_orig['long'],
                lat1=row_orig['lat'],
                lon2=row_dest['long'],
                lat2=row_dest['lat'])
            for _, row_dest in df.iterrows()
            if row_dest['val'] == 1])

df['min'] = df.apply(lambda row: distances.get(row['i'], 0), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works quite well. I'll try to find a way to reduce the sample where I compute the distance to improve the time consuming because I have 12k rows with 0 and quite the same with 1.

Comment: You think we can improve the time consuming only making difference in 'close' latitude and longitude? Because 2hours for a distance is little bit long ahah

Comment: @AlexGermain I added another version of my solution, maybe this one is faster for all your data.