# How to make sqrt and cos available in tarantool SQL?

Tags: sql, lua, tarantool

I'm trying to estimate a distance using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53712712/1620210) formula, but when I try to execute it in tarantool sql

```
box.execute [[SELECT "weight" + sqrt( cos("lat" - 12.31252) * ...]]
```

it shows:

```
function SQRT() is not available in SQL
Function 'COS' does not exist
```

how to make those [functions](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_sql/sql_statements_and_clauses/) available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not yet available in tarantool SQL out-of-the-box, but you can use `box.schema.func.create` to call arbitrary lua code from SQL. Here's what you need to do:

```
box.schema.func.create(
  'COS', {
    returns="number", 
    body="function (num) return math.cos(num) end", 
    is_sandboxed=false,
    param_list={"number"}, 
    exports = {'LUA', 'SQL'}
  })
```

Then call it like this:

```
box.execute("SELECT cos(123)")
```

To learn more about this, you can refer to the [documentation on calling Lua from SQL](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_sql/sql_plus_lua/#sql-calling-lua).

Comment: How do I create this function on startup ? I'm running Tarantool in a docker container.