# how to get distance between two places in kilometer in google map v2 using LatLng

Tags: android, google-maps

In my android application, 
I've to calculate distance between user's current location and the point that user taps on the map.
I'm using this function to calculate:

```
     public double CalculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
     int Radius=6371;//radius of earth in Km         
     double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
     double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
     double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
     double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
     double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
     double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
     double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    double valueResult= Radius*c;
    double km=valueResult/1;
    DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
    int kmInDec =  Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
    double meter=valueResult%1000;
    int  meterInDec= Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
    Log.i("Radius Value",""+valueResult+"   KM  "+kmInDec+" Meter   "+meterInDec);

    return Radius * c;
    }
```

But I'm getting very long distance as the result , for eg. I'm getting like 10947 km as the distance between two places which is only about 20 m far . Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search about Haversine equation. here's one implementation which return the distance in Meter:

```
public static double haversine(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);

    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);

    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

    return R * c;
}
```

Where R = 6371000;

Answer (score 4):

Android offers method for calculating distance between two lat/lon points.

```
android.location.Location.distanceBetween(double startLatitude,
    double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method :

```
        private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2,
            double lon2) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2))
                + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2))
                * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        return (dist);
    }
```

Or just check this [conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations)

Comment: can u provide deg2rad method?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981916/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-their-longitude-and-latitu ...

Answer (score 0):

Method to calculate distance in Kilometers

```
public static double distanceKM(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2,
            double lon2) {
        int EARTH_RADIUS_KM = 6371;
        double lat1Rad = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        double lat2Rad = Math.toRadians(lat2);
        double deltaLonRad = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);

        double dist_travelled = Math
                .acos(Math.sin(lat1Rad) * Math.sin(lat2Rad) + Math.cos(lat1Rad)
                        * Math.cos(lat2Rad) * Math.cos(deltaLonRad))
                * EARTH_RADIUS_KM;

        dist_travelled = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.######")
                .format(dist_travelled));
        return dist_travelled;

    }
```