# I have two latlong values. one for source and other for destination..In which format latlong value should pass to find distance between them

Tags: android

```
DIRECTION_URL_API = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"
DIRECTION_URL_API + "origin=" + origin + "&destination=" + destination  + "&sensor=true" + "&mode=" +typeOpt+"&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY  ;
```

I am using this format but its not working

Please suggest me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate distance between two locations using their longitude and latitude value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981916/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-their-longitude-and-latitu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find distance following way
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=21.1702,72.8311&destination=21.7051,72.9959&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving

origin=lat1,long1
destination=lat2,long2

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below method to calculate the distance between **two points**

```
/**
 * Returns Distance in kilometers (km)
 */
public static String distance(double startLat, double startLong, double endLat, double endLong) {
    Location startPoint = new Location("locationA");
    startPoint.setLatitude(startLat);
    startPoint.setLongitude(startLong);

    Location endPoint = new Location("locationA");
    endPoint.setLatitude(endLat);
    endPoint.setLongitude(endLong);

    return String.format("%.2f", startPoint.distanceTo(endPoint) / 1000); //KMs
}
```

Method usage -

```
String mDistance  = distance(startLat,
                    startLong,
                    endLat,endLng)).concat("km");
```