# How to Add Arraylist Lat Long value into new LatLng class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, arraylist

Please Help me,
I have stored my lat, long value into `arrayList<String>`, but I'm not able to add it to new LatLng class.

I have to fetch Lat, Long value by `json` and add it to (String) `ArrayList<String>`.

I want to add my all ArrayList Lat, Long into latlng class, where i can see it using polyline.

But i'm able to get one lat and long and it shows in my google map. But i'm 
not able to get all `ArrayList` value.
I tried many times. And How to Measure Distance By Lat and Long
Below is my code;

```
ArrayList<String> arr;

 if(b!=null){
           arr = (ArrayList<String>)b.getStringArrayList("array_list");
           // System.out.println(arr);
        }
    String s=arr.toString();
    System.out.println(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));

    String ss=s.substring(1,s.length()-1);
    System.out.println(ss);
    d=ss.split(",");
    for (int i=0;i<d.length;i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            dd=d[i];
            System.out.println(dd +"all even");
        }else{
            nd=d[i];

            System.out.println(nd +"all odd");
        }


    }

    List<LatLng> point = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    double pointY[]={Double.parseDouble(nd)};
    double pointX[]={Double.parseDouble(dd)};
    for (int i = 0 ; i < pointX.length; i++){

        point.add(new LatLng(pointX[i],pointY[i]));
    }
```

Comment: may i ask why you dont use a json framework for parsing the json into a pojo ? I suggest a framework called jackson

Comment: Dear sir, I'm able to get all json and i have stored it into arraylist & pass it's data using putExtra. But my problem is i'm not able to add arraylist value into my google map. I'm only able to get one marker. But i have 5 lat, long value.

Comment: Instead of doing all this weird string manipulation create a custom arraylist of modal class and add data to your list using either constructor or getter/setter. After that loop through the list and get your data

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

your pointY, pointX were initialized with last item. Put those in for loop to fill all the values

```
ArrayList<String> arr;
   Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
 if(b!=null){
           arr = (ArrayList<String>)b.getStringArrayList("array_list");
           // System.out.println(arr);
        }
    String s=arr.toString();
    System.out.println(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));

String ss=s.substring(1,s.length()-1);
System.out.println(ss);


d=ss.split(",");
 List<Double> pointY = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> pointX = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0;i<d.length;i++){
    if(i%2==0){
        dd=d[i];
        pointX.add(Double.parseDouble(dd));
        System.out.println(dd +"all even");
    }else{
        nd=d[i];
        pointY.add(Double.parseDouble(nd));
        System.out.println(nd +"all odd");
    }


}

List<LatLng> point = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
for (int i = 0 ; i < pointX.size(); i++){

    point.add(new LatLng(pointX.get(i),pointY.get(i)));
}
```

Comment: getting initialize is not allow here pointX[x++]={Double.parseDouble(dd)};

Comment: wow.. Thank U so much, now I'm able to get 2 polyline :) .. Thank U Sir,

Comment: @HarishKumar glad! that helped

Comment: Give me 2 mints i'm adding 2 another lat, longs thank you sir

Comment: Dear sir, I have another query. How can i calculate my all distance?

Comment: @HarishKumar try the solution available here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981916/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-their-longitude-and-latitu

Comment: Dear sir, i have asked it on stackoverflow please see it :. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003275/how-to-calculate-distance-using-lat-and-lon

Comment: I'm able to calculate one and last lat lon distance.

Comment: Thank U sir, I got solution i had to sum all of value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what and why you are trying to do and your code is not readable(sorry your coding style is horrible). But I can show a snippet about how I would do this.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // some example data
    String coord1lat = "15.235235";
    String coord1lng = "31.776776";
    String coord2lat = "34.334346";
    String coord2lng = "31.776776";
    String[] coordinatesStringList = {coord1lat, coord1lng, coord2lat, coord2lng};

    List<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    for(int i=0; i<coordinatesStringList.length; i+=2){
        LatLng pont = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(coordinatesStringList[i]), Double.parseDouble(coordinatesStringList[i+1]));
        latLngList.add(point);
    }
}
```

Again, I highly discourage you to store latitudes and longitudes in one array. I don't know your case but try to store them in a couples at least. 
Like `String coord1 = "15.23235,16.232342"`

Comment: Dear sir, i have arraylist<String> like = 28.6613494,77.1483808, 28.6613494,77.1483808, 28.550819, 77.255524, 28.6613486,77.1483728, 28.6613486,77.1483728, 28.6613486,77.1483728. how can i added it. if i would not splite it.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to say. You don't have to split it if it's an array. You would've splitted that if you would have all the coordinates in on String(not string array). Like
`String coordinates = "28.6613494,77.1483808, 28.6613494,77.1483808, 28.550819, 77.255524, 28.6613486,77.1483728, 28.6613486,77.1483728, 28.6613486,77.1483728" `
But it's not like that, is it?

Comment: oh. I understood your logic. Thank You.

Comment: And please name you variables a little more appropriate. 'dd' and 'ss' don't tell much about your code and you will get crazy soon trying to debug something you've written couple of weeks ago

Comment: I'm not able to use it.  Please Give full solution with arraylist<String>. I'm using ArrayList not Array.