# How to get Sum of Lat and Long Km Value?

Tags: java, android

I have used Stackoverflow : [How to calculate distance between two locations using their longitude and latitude value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981916/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-their-longitude-and-latitu)

Distance Calculator Method,

```
private String getDistanceOnRoad(double latitude, double longitude,
        double prelatitute, double prelongitude) {
    String result_in_kms = "";
    String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin="
            + latitude + "," + longitude + "&destination=" + prelatitute
            + "," + prelongitude + "&sensor=false&units=metric";
    String tag[] = { "text" };
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(is);
        if (doc != null) {
            NodeList nl;
            ArrayList args = new ArrayList();
            for (String s : tag) {
                nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(s);
                if (nl.getLength() > 0) {
                    Node node = nl.item(nl.getLength() - 1);
                    args.add(node.getTextContent());
                } else {
                    args.add(" - ");
                }
            }
            result_in_kms = String.format("%s", args.get(0));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result_in_kms;
}
```

But Don't know how to get sum of all distance using double, this method return string value and i'm not able to calculate or sum string km value.

Comment: Double.parseDouble(12.88999);? Doesn't it makes to add values ?

Comment: not able to get sum using Double.parseDouble(result_in_kms);

Comment: Why ? Whats so tricky about it ? What error you got

Comment: NumberFormateException: ""

Answer (score 0):

map has predefined method to calculate distance in meter between 2 location

```
firstLocation.distanceTo(currentLocation)
```

Comment: Thank u Pratim P I'll try.. But is it possible to get sum of distance using above method

Comment: really don't know sir.