# How to calculate distance and time between two lat long in Android?

Tags: android, geolocation, distance, android-maps-v2

I am using `for-loop` below. The code calculates correctly if it is not inside the loop, but I want to create a list with no. of distance and time.

```
KIEL = new LatLng(lat, log);                    
for(i=0;i<jarray.length;i++){
    KIEL = new LatLng(lat, log);
    doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, KIEL,
        GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
    duration = "" + md.getDurationValue(doc);
    distance = md.getDistanceText(doc);

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("distance", distance);
    map.put("time", duration );

    // // adding HashList to ArrayList
    locationlist.add(map);                      
}
```

`doc` is an object of `Document` class which is calculating distance and time between two locations. But when I am using this method inside the loop, it will show no data. How to fix it?

Comment: public static void distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Comment: But my location come from database and used in loop so I think its not working for my problem .

Comment: use this link..http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/

Comment: what is the meaning of "md"

Answer (score 3):

use Location.distanceTo(Location) it will give you distance between two different Location's.

like `distance = currentLocation.distanceTo(newLocation);`

Comment: Thanks for given to me solution but still finding solution for getting time ..??

Comment: tell me your problem ?

Comment: I want to calculate time taken between to location .

Comment: For reach from source to destination How much time taken between to location

Comment: go through this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694380/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude-what-am-i-doi..and if think it useful then upvote it..

Comment: Not Working I want to calculating time in min between two location .

Answer (score 0):

download library from here and import into your project

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

follow this link for you distance

googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/

use like this and you will get perfect area and distance and all ...

SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(LatLng from,LatLng to);