# Spherical Geometry lib for java

Tags: java, geometry, apache-commons-math

I want to get distance of two cities having their latitude and longitude. 
Is there a java lib to do it? Apache common math seems to have a spherical class. Is there any one used it?

Comment: A pretty good estimate of the [great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Formulas) is simple.  (The first formula works fine, even with distances a meter or two apart, when you're calculating with doubles.  So you can largely ignore the precision warnings on that page.)  I say "estimate" because the formulas don't account for the fact that the earth is a hair fatter than it is tall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer:
[Calculating distance between two points, using latitude longitude, what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694380/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude-what-am-i-doi)

Doesn't utilize a library, but the accepted answer will solve your problem.