# Haversin formula for distance less than 5 meter

Tags: java, haversine

I am trying to use the haversin formula to prevent updating the mysql table. I am implementing an app based on crowdsorucing where the data `mac, route, lat, long` is being recorded by the devices of the  passangers im bus and send to the server.

My database table has  mac address as `UNIQUE KEY`.  So to avoid that other  passanger in the same bus to store their data in the table I would filter these requests by using the `Haversin formula` but I tried it with tow point which are roughly 20 meter close to each other but I am gettig number of `4803.800129810092`

```
//calculate the distance between the request's sender and all other request in the ArrayList. 

  private double haversineDistance(LatLong x, LatLong y) {  
        final int R = 6371; // Radious of the earth
    double xLat = x.getLatitude();
    double xLon = x.getLongitude();
    double yLat = y.getLongitude();
    double yLon = y.getLongitude();
    ;
    double latDistance = toRad(yLat - xLat);
    double lonDistance = toRad(yLon - xLon);
    double a = Math.sin(latDistance / 2) * Math.sin(latDistance / 2)
            + Math.cos(toRad(xLat)) * Math.cos(toRad(yLat))
            * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2) * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double distance = R * c;

      System.out.println("The distance between two lat and long is:" + distance);

        return distance;

    }
```

Comment: `lat2=y.getLatitude()` ...

Comment: As @rpax noted you are getting the longitude and storing in in the latitude.

Comment: gfelisberto: ok  thnaks in which unity is the result being calculated? How I can get it in meter?

Comment: The units of the result are the units you specify R in, at the moment km. The haversin is overkill for finding whether two points are within 5m though

Comment: There is lots of existing code to do this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694380/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude-what-am-i-doi/16794680#16794680

Answer (score 0):

Haversine is overkill for this. Pythagoras is adequate.

Below is javascript function to return distances in metres. I am sure you can convert to Java'

```
function Pyth(lat1,lat2,lng1,lng2){
x = toRad(lng2-lng1) ;
y = toRad(lat2-lat1);
R = 6371000; // gives d in metres
d = sqrt(x*x + y*y) * R;
return d;
}
```

Comment: With havsen formula I am getting value of 4-15 meter when I pick two close fixes but with `Pythagoras `  I am getting value like `1.1979775925924383E7, 1.1979777593853703E7, 1.1979940093453636E7` what does these values mean? I getting these values when I pick far points too?

Comment: For distances less than 10 meters the 5th decimal place of lat/lng coordinates is significant.[**See**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees).

Comment: does that mean I have to cosider only the 5th decimal place in the result `d` of the `pyth()` function or I have to pass the 5th decimal place of the longitude and latitude to the function?

Comment: @MrPencil see corrected formula had + instead of - . The 5th decimal place refers to geographic coordinates.  You can round d to whatever you think is required.