# Sort Collection of GPS Locations by distance to current GPS Location

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, gps

Given a collection of Location objects which have a longitude and latitude, how can I sort this list based on each Locations distance to a current Location object?

I have a method which can calculate the distance in meters between two Location objects.

Is `Collections.Sort()` appropriate here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write a comparator:

```
static final Location origin;

public class LocationComparator implements Comparator {
  @Override
  public int compare(Location o1, Location o2) {
    return Doubles.compare(distance(o1.lat, origin.lat, o1.lon, origin.lon, 0, 0),
                           distance(o2.lat, origin.lat, o2.lon, origin.lon, 0, 0));
  }
}
```

Where distance is as defined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694380/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude-what-am-i-doi). This compares two points based on their distance from origin.

And then you can sort by calling:

```
Collections.sort(latLonCollection, new LocationComparator());
```

Comment: Can you explain briefly what your doing in ur `compare()`.

Comment: I added a sentence. Basically compares 2 points based on their distance from origin.

Comment: Oh sorry missed the `distance()`. Great thanks. I like this method since I do not have to traverse the List setting the origin for each Location. It's just set in the comparator. Simple.

Answer (score 3):

This is an update to Benjy's answer, except using the `Location` class's built in functions. Its been isolated to include the origin as part of the constructor.

```
public class LocationComparator implements Comparator<Location>
{
    Location origin;
    LocationComparator(Location origin){
        this.origin= origin;
    }
    public int compare(Location left, Location right) {
        return Float.compare(origin.distanceTo(left), origin.distanceTo(right));
    }
}
```

Used as follows

```
Collections.sort(latLonCollection, new LocationComparator(originLocation));
```