# Android Geofences with Google Map api V2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-geofence

i am working on android application in which i have to define many regions on google map, for that i use google map's OnClicklistner to define circle and i add Geofence to that region so that if user passes/exits from that region then it should trigger notification that this region is Enterd or Exited with time..i  already tried example from [1]:http://paulusworld.com/technical/android-geofences-update 
how to achive this..plese help

Comment: thats easy show your code what you achieved and what else you want to do.

Comment: i also want to show notification even when app is killed or in Background

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1jXkMMNkEv9QzdZYzNJT29HTW8/view?usp=sharing   Here is the Code..

Comment: 1. Its hard for me to review your whole code but there is a algo. for checking the distance between the latlon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694380/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude-what-am-i-doi............2. by using the center of geofence and the current location you can find whether the location is inside or outside of geofence.