# List cardview by location

Tags: android, location, cardview

I am trying to show the cardview created programatically, that contains an image view and a text view of registered user, I'd like to order it by location, so the closest user to me will be shown first, I overridden the compare method, getting the location and subtracting the available user location, but it doesn't work properly. Anyone can help?

```
@Override
            public int compare(Users o1, Users o2) {
                return (int)(o1.getDistance()-o2.getDistance());
            }
        } );






public void getDistance(){
for(Users u: UsersResource.getInstance().getList()){
    float[] distance = new float[2];

Location.distanceBetween( loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(),
    u.getLatitude(), u.getLongtitude(), distance);

u.setDistance( distance[0] );
    System.out.println("distance "+ distance[0]);

     }}
```

Comment: what does getDistance return? how are you calculating distance? using Lats &Lons?

Comment: My guess would be to use a Math vector. to calculate the distance and direction.

Comment: Yes it returns latitude and longtitude, I updated my post with the getDistance method

Comment: would you mind to explain me the Math vector

Comment: simple vectors which we learned in Math class. -> https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html 

I am not sure if it will help here. but I guess you need a proper solution. Let me see if I can find something for you

Comment: This should help you sir! -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/16794680/6142219

Comment: let me know if it helps!

Answer (score -2):

you can use cardview.orderbylocation