# Find closest entries in a list by comparing with one entry

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have a `Unit` class which has lots of fields in it as shown below:

```
public class Unit {
  private final int id;
  private final int beds;
  private final String city;
  private final double lat;
  private final double lon;

  // constructors and getters here
  // toString method

}
```

I now have a List of `Unit` which is a `List` object which contains lots of Units. Now I need to find the nearest Units from `List` object to `Unit x`. Cap the results by limit.

```
  private List<Unit> nearestUnits(List<Unit> lists, Unit x, int limit) {
    List<Unit> output = new ArrayList<>();

    // how do I sort lists object in such a way so that I can get nearest units here to "x"?

    return output;
  }
```

We have lat/long present in the `Unit` class so we can use that to calculate euclidean distance and do the comparison. I am confused on how to sort the list of units by shortest distance and get the nearest units. I am working with Java 7 as of now so I can't use Java 8.

Comment: 1) Create a `Map` with the units as keys and the distances to unit x as value. 2) Use one of the solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values) to sort the map by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that you know how to calculate the distance, so my code below does not include the calculation so I assume you can implement the `calculateDistance()` method. I use a `TreeMap` which automatically sorts entries added to it and class `Double` implements `Comparable` so you don't need to handle the sorting. The `Iterator` will return the keys sorted by the calculated distance.

```
private List<Unit> nearestUnits(List<Unit> lists, Unit x, int limit) {
    TreeMap<Double, Unit> sorted = new TreeMap<>();
    List<Unit> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Unit unit : lists) {
        Double distance = calculateDistance(unit, x);
        sorted.put(distance, unit);
    }
    Set<Double> keys = sorted.keySet();
    Iterator<Double> iter = keys.iterator();
    int count = 0;
    while (iter.hasNext() && count < limit) {
        Double key = iter.next();
        Unit val = sorted.get(key);
        output.add(val);
        count++;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: This is more unreadable and FYI `TreeMap::put` is `O(log n)` (this is not a `HashMap`), so inserting `n` elements would be `O(n log n)`. `ArrayList::sort` is also `O(n log n)` and it is much much better in readability.

Comment: @Jai, Cool, so please provide your own answer and enlighten us all.

Answer (score 2):

// this distance method reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16794680/6138660

```
public static double distance(double lat1, double lat2, double lon1,
        double lon2) {
    final int R = 6371; // Radius of the earth

    double latDistance = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double lonDistance = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    double a = Math.sin(latDistance / 2) * Math.sin(latDistance / 2)
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2))
            * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2) * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double distance = R * c * 1000; // convert to meters

    distance = Math.pow(distance, 2);

    return Math.sqrt(distance);
}

private List<Unit> nearestUnits(List<Unit> lists, Unit x, int limit) {


    lists.sort(new Comparator<Unit>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Unit o1, Unit o2) {

            double flagLat = x.getLat();
            double flagLon = x.getLon();

            double o1DistanceFromFlag = distance(flagLat, o1.getLat(), flagLon, o1.getLon());
            double o2DistanceFromFlag = distance(flagLat, o2.getLat(), flagLon, o2.getLon());

            return Double.compare(o1DistanceFromFlag, o2DistanceFromFlag);
        }
    });

    return lists.subList(0, limit);;
  }
```

Comment: This would work, but it would be faster to create a list of say `UnitDistance { Unit unit; double distance; }` and then sort it by distance: the distance would be computed only once per unit Other option: fill a a `TreeMap<Double,Unit>`.