# How I can find the distance in kilometre between two location with their longitude and latitude using java and android

Tags: java, android

How I can find the distance in kilometre between two location with their longitude and latitude using java and android?
I retrieve the longitude and latitude from the Firebase database which I stored them in it, but the problem I need a way to find the actual distance not the straight line distance.

Comment: the actual distance as in accounting for the curvature of the earth?

Comment: yes, as when it is displayed in the google map when put two location and give us the time to reach it and the distance

Comment: I need to calculate this distance from the  longitude and latitude that I have

Comment: If you want to travel time and distance by road I would suggest using a map api like google, apple or other....

Comment: Just divided this by 1000 or adjust algorithm (this can also take into account altitude differences : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16794680/4252352 - remember this is "as the crow flies".

Comment: Can use it with the longitude and latitude that is already taken ?

Comment: @silversunhunter this will give the straight line distance not the actual distance as it displayed in map

Comment: what is the actual distance? [Great-Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)?

Comment: For short distances, where straight-line calculations are fine, use `Location.distanceBetween()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])

Comment: @Great-Circle I meant of actual distance is the distance that displayed in google map when I put my location and my destination which consider the heights and deviations of roads

Comment: distances between to points using geographical transport infrastructure routes is a lot more complicated as it involves weighed graphs, adjacency lists, Dijkstra's algorithm etc.  Having the start and end points is the entry point into all of this.  I would look into what information is available to you, other than start and end points and then invest some time learning weighed graphs.