# Do GPS operation for lat/long with geotools

Tags: java, gps, geotools

First I'm a newbie in GPS system.
I have GPS coordinates in WGS-84 receive from a basic GPS in USB.
I want to calculate the distance beetween this two point.
But I want the plane distances. So I have first to convert this coordinates to an other CRS example "EPSG:2154" for Lambert 93. And after calulate the distance.
I try to use Geotools but the examples in the docs are not releveant for me and I d'ont understand how to do this.
I thought  first I have to found the matching transform like this :

```
DefaultGeographicCRS crs = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
    //EPSG:2154 RGF93 / Lambert-93 (Google it)
    CoordinateReferenceSystem crs2 = CRS.decode("EPSG:2154");
    MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(crs, crs2);
```

But after reading docs it seems the transformation works for x,y coordinates not lat/long. And i do not understand how to use the MathTransform as it doesn't accept point with lat/long. I also try the example below but executing the code doesn't give the same results for me.

[Calculating distance between two points, using latitude longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694380/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude)

So if anyone with good knowledge in GPS and Geotools is able to help me.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the whole code or a reproducible example?
Try to swap the x and y values, is the result correct then?

Comment: From the example in link I try to swap x and y value but result is never the same. The whole code is not interesting as this is only the example I provide in link with the other two lines. And I'm stuck with the MathTransform don't know how to use it.

Comment: That code looks good to me, what does not work? X and Y are just variables, so lat, lon or possibly lon, lat are fine as inputs

Comment: I didn't say the code is not good. May be I have to edit my question. For example I have two lat/lon in WGS84. First I want to transform it into LAMBERT93 plane projection. And then calculate distance between these two points. And do this by using Geotools. But I lack some information to understand how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want the distance between two GPS points then you can use the `GeodeticCalculator` to calculate this in metres (and the Units library to convert it to any distance unit you like:

```
import javax.measure.MetricPrefix;
import javax.measure.Quantity;
import javax.measure.quantity.Length;

import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS.AxisOrder;
import org.geotools.referencing.GeodeticCalculator;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;

import si.uom.SI;
import systems.uom.common.USCustomary;
import tech.units.indriya.quantity.Quantities;

public class OrthodromicDistance2 {
  /**
   * take two pairs of lat/long and return bearing and distance.
   * 
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DefaultGeographicCRS crs = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
    if (args.length != 4) {
      System.err.println("Need 4 numbers lat_1 lon_1 lat_2 lon_2");
      return;
    }
    GeometryFactory geomFactory = new GeometryFactory();
    Point[] points = new Point[2];
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < 2; i++, k += 2) {
      double x = Double.parseDouble(args[k]);
      double y = Double.parseDouble(args[k + 1]);
      if (CRS.getAxisOrder(crs).equals(AxisOrder.NORTH_EAST)) {
        System.out.println("working with a lat/lon crs");
        points[i] = geomFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(x, y));
      } else {
        System.out.println("working with a lon/lat crs");
        points[i] = geomFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(y, x));
      }

    }
    System.out.println(points[0]);
    System.out.println(points[1]);
    double distance = 0.0;

    GeodeticCalculator calc = new GeodeticCalculator(crs);
    calc.setStartingGeographicPoint(points[0].getX(), points[0].getY());
    calc.setDestinationGeographicPoint(points[1].getX(), points[1].getY());

    distance = calc.getOrthodromicDistance();
    double bearing = calc.getAzimuth();

    Quantity<Length> dist = Quantities.getQuantity(distance, SI.METRE);
    System.out.println(dist.to(MetricPrefix.KILO(SI.METRE)).getValue() + " Km");
    System.out.println(dist.to(USCustomary.MILE).getValue() + " miles");
    System.out.println("Bearing " + bearing + " degrees");
  }
}
```

This will work for any points on the globe no matter how far apart they are and makes use of [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/index.html) by Charles F. F. Karney and gives an accuracy of nanometres.

If however, you want to carry out more geometry operations on your points/lines etc then you are right to want to transform your points to a projected CRS (such as Lambert 93):

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem wgs84= CRS.decode("EPSG:4326", true);
CoordinateReferenceSystem lambert = CRS.decode("EPSG:2154", true);
MathTransform toMeters= CRS.findMathTransform(wgs84, lambert);

Geometry output1 = JTS.transform(input1, toMeters);
Geometry output2 = JTS.transform(input2, toMeters);
double distance = output1.distance(output2);
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly and feet the previous result I had in a C++ soft. Many thanks Ian